# CSS3 PIE - Making it work on Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, css, css3pie

i want to corret the problems i have when my site is loaded on IE. I made a search and found PIE which by the description looked a good solution.

However, and after looking at some posts here and at the oficial site of pie i'm not being able to make it work.

First of all, i just placed the PIE.htc file on the folder of my website. But then why there are other files in folder i downloaded from the PIE site? There's no need for them?

Second, i'm applying this way to make round corners on IE?

```
    ul#menu span.description{
    width:120px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#99FF33;
    border:3px solid #0000FF;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    display:block;
    font-size:22px;
    padding:10px;
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 6px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 6px #000;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 6px #000;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
    -pie-border-radius:10px;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}
```

is it wrong?

And last, after the search i made here, i read something about adding a .htaccess file to the same location as the PIE.htc folder. But i have some doubs here. Can i give any name to the file and the extension ".htaccess"? is that what i need to do? That was what i did with the following code in the file:

```
AddType text/x-component .htc
```

Still, after all this i'm not being able to see round corners on IE 8? Any hints?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The path to the .htc file is relative to the CSS document from which it is referenced.

Look in the debugger (F12 in IE) and make sure it is requesting the correct file in the network console and getting a good response.

Comment: Hmm, sorry Eric, but in the debugger how can i check that?

Comment: I guess it's in the right place. i have the file .htc in the same folder as the .html/php file being displayed.

Comment: It's solved Eric.
Since it's a wordpress website, i found the solution on this link:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Working_with_PIE_in_WordPress_for_older_IE_versions

Thanks anyway!